# checking a multiple hashsets within a dictionary to get the key value

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

So I'm trying to work though a scrabble game, I'm trying to use a dictionary with an int hashset lists. I've put the letters in groups based off their value (key=int=score) as below.

```
HashSet<char> pointsONEList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'e', 'a', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'r', 't', 'l', 's', 'u' });
HashSet<char> pointsTwoList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'd', 'g' });
HashSet<char> pointsThreeList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'b', 'c', 'm', 'p' });
HashSet<char> pointsFourList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'f', 'h', 'v', 'w', 'y' });
HashSet<char> pointsFiveList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'k' });
HashSet<char> pointsEightList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'j', 'x' });
HashSet<char> pointsTenList = new HashSet<char>(new char[] { 'q', 'z' });

Dictionary<int, HashSet<char>> letterPoints = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<char>>();

letterPoints.Add(1, pointsONEList);
letterPoints.Add(2, pointsTwoList);
letterPoints.Add(3, pointsThreeList);
letterPoints.Add(4, pointsFourList);
letterPoints.Add(5, pointsFiveList);
letterPoints.Add(8, pointsEightList);
letterPoints.Add(10, pointsTenList);
```

Next i need to find a way to take apart a word and find each character in the word, find it in the list and then add to another dictionary using the given word and the sum of all its digits.

this is what i have so far

```
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    string W = Console.ReadLine();

    int wordValue=0;
    char[] splitWord = W.ToCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < splitWord.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < letterPoints.Count; h++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I cant get it to search the entire dictionary

Comment: hashset only stores distinct items

Comment: It's easier to just have an array of size 26, which holds points for each of letters, and reference it like `Points[letter - 'A']`

Comment: or a dictionary with characters as keys

Answer (score 2):

With using `LINQ`, you can do it in a single line:

```
var points = splitWord.Sum(c => letterPoints.First(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(c)).Key)
```

What this code does is: for each character in the `splitWord` find the `HashSet` from the letterPoints that contains the character, get the corresponding key, and sum all the keys up and get the total point.

Comment: @TravisJeffery glad that this solved your problem but I would consider using a dictionary where keys are the chars and values are the points instead as suggested in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779317/checking-a-multiple-hashsets-within-a-dictionary-to-get-the-key-value/42779470?noredirect=1#comment72673311_42779317) You can still use this method with a dictionary like that, I'm gonna leave that to you.